# Using a series to find a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So we had a homework assignment where we are asked to solve a differential equation through a series,I am not sure where to begin for this as we have not actually gone over this. If someone could help guide me through the process I would greatly appreciate it.
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^n(n!)x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}$$
Also I tried searching for the input for factorial but no luck if someone could edit it or let me know how to add it I would appreaciate that.

Comment: And, where is your differential equation..?

Comment: Got it, Ill come back later and update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know how to derive a series solution to a differential equation and are just struggling to work backwards to find the correct DE for this series.

There is a very powerful method that can be used here: trial and error (with some intuition) :D

$$y= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n 2^n n!}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$$
This looks like an integral of x^2n so differentiate it:
$$y'= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n 2^n n! x^{2n}$$
This is immediately nicer to work with:
$$x^2y'= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n 2^n n! x^{2n+2}$$
$$\frac {d}{dx}[x^2y']= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n 2^n n!(2n+2) x^{2n+1}$$
$$2xy'+x^2y''= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n 2^{n+1} (n+1)! x^{2n+1}$$
This is beginning to look a lot like the series for y':
$$-x(2xy'+x^2y'')= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} 2^{n+1} (n+1)! x^{2n+2}$$
$$-x(2xy'+x^2y'')= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} 2^{n} n! x^{2n} -1$$
$$ \therefore -x(2xy'+x^2y'')=y'-1 \\ $$

$$ \\ x^2y''-(2x^2+1)y'+1=0  \\$$ This is your DE unless I made any calculation errors.